# Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined

Tags: angular

I have a Angular Application and recently added this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/geo-tz

I created a new class test.ts

```
import {find} from "geo-tz";

export class Test {


  public getTimezone() {

    console.log(find(47.650499, -122.350070));
  }
}
```

this is called from a page like the following:

```
    const blah = new Test();
    blah.getTimezone();
```

however when I try to open the page I get the following error in the console:

> E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/vendor.js - Line 2288 -
> Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: __dirname is
> not defined
> ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The package you're trying to use is a Node-based one.

Angular is browser-based.

You cannot use Node-based packages into browser-based applications.